# Calling 2 different stylesheets wordpress (some logic within)

Tags: php, wordpress, stylesheet

Hi guys I have some logic here that does not seem to be working for me. Currently I am trying to use two different stylesheets in wordpress. Here is the logic:

```
        <?php 

$url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if ($url=="theurl.com")
    {
        ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetforthispage.css" /><?;
    }
    else
   {
        ?><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheetforotherpages.css" /><?;
    }

    ?>
```

My problem is that the URL that I am trying to use the other stylesheet for is the homepage, and everytime I try this logic is does not seem to work? All help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked what `$url` returns?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/")
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/homepage.css" type="text/css"/>';
    else
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/other-pages.css" type="text/css"/>';
?>
```

Comment: You can use my logic, it will work.  If you want to know where your logic went wrong: your assignment statement is wrong, the quotation marks are in the wrong spot.  It should be:

`$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`

Then call `echo $url;` to see what the output is.

So if your URL was "www.theurl.com" and the page you put the above statement on was called "test.php", $url will have the value "www.theurl.com/test.php".